# Can A Boost Charger For iPhone Be Used With An iPod?

Tags: ipod

I have an iPod Touch 6th generation.  Can I use a Belkin Boost Charger made for an iPhone/iPad to charge it? It's 18w USB-C and 12w USB-A. My concern is about the wattage, not about the brand.

Comment: There are also other duplicates I'm sure. Basically, as long as you're using a good Lightning cable, then any USB charging source you plug it in to will work to charge your device (regardless of whether it's an iPod Touch or iPhone). Charging is regulated by the device, so it really should not get damaged by too much wattage etc. The only problems arise when chargers don't provide enough charge to actually charge a device (but that's not the situation you're in as you're effectively talking about a fast charger).

Comment: Thank you. I just don't want to damage the iPod by using a charger that is too powerful. I wasn't aware the device regulated the charging.